# Python requests' response text is unable to parse

Tags: python, html, encoding, python-requests

I have a request that send specific headers and payload to get a pdf content.
In browser's Network tab the response look like this:

[image]

But when I use python request and beautiful soup modules, they all cannot parse this response as well as it can not be written to any file to see it properly.
Here is a part of what I got:

`//OK[1,["\x3Chtml\x3E\n\x3Chead\x3E\n\x3CMETA http-equiv\x3D\"Content-Type\" content\x3D\"text/html; charset\x3DUTF-8\"\x3E\n\x3Ctitle\x3EДанные ... \x3C/h2\x3E\n\x3C/div\x3E\n\x3C/div\x3E\n\x3C/body\x3E\n\x3C/html\x3E\n"],0,7]`

I tried splitting text to keep only a part that starts and ends with `html` tag but Beautiful soup couldn't replace hex symbols to a normal view. `.encode()` and `.decode('utf-8')` also didn't helped

What would you recommend?

Comment: Before you make your request, try doing `r.encoding = 'utf-8'`. Is the result from printing out `r.text` all messed up, or is it only after you run it through beautiful soup that it looks that way?

Comment: @wp-overwatch.com I tried as you recommended but it didn't help. Still I have the same mess in a raw request data.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing it this way:

```
html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
```

If not, do it this way, it should work. This is because if you want the text of an HTML file you should use the `.text` property.

Comment: I'd argue the reverse: pass the raw bytes.  Beautiful Soup has powerful heuristics for decoding whereas requests will either try to use the declared encoding or fall back to Latin-1.